# Adding scroll animation to page jump URL in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, page-jump

I'm trying to make a smooth scroll when I press a link (in this case `Contact us`) to an anchor tag (`#contact_us`) present in a different section but on the same page.
The issue is that there is no smooth scroll whatsoever, it just immediately sends me to the anchor tag.
How can I make sure that there is a smooth scroll effect when I press the link?
Should I use JS or just CSS (if such a thing is possible) because I'm using PHP?

Thanks in advance for the tips :D.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a small bit of css:

```css
body{ scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

Check out the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) for more info

Comment: Let me know if that works for you, it is supported on most modern browsers: 
https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can add smooth scroll this way.
Check console log error if any other script get conflict.

```js
$(".scrollMe").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".bottom").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.top{background: green;height:700px;width:100%;}
.bottom{background: pink;height:700px;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="scrollMe" href="#">Scroll Down</a>
<div class="top">
</div>

<div class="bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is I'm using PHP not HTML and fore some reason it isn't working but I will try again

Comment: @Don can you share the scroll part of the php code .

Comment: <li class="nav-item gore">
                        <a class="nav-link scrollMe" href="#footer">Contact us</a>
                    </li>

Comment: Did you check the console is there any error.